# Guice provider for UriInfo using RestEasy

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, guice, resteasy

I have a web app which is being ported from Jersey to RestEasy. The app uses Guice for CDI.

The app uses a Guice provider to inject UriInfo. In the Jersey version this code looked like this

```
public static class JerseyIntegrationModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override protected void configure() {
        bind(WebApplication.class).to(WebApplicationImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
    }

    @Provides @RequestScoped
    public HttpContext getHttpContext(WebApplication webapp) {
      return webapp.getThreadLocalHttpContext();
    }

    @Provides @RequestScoped
    public UriInfo getUriInfo(HttpContext httpContext) {
      return httpContext.getUriInfo();
    }
}
```

All these classes `WebApplication`, `HttpContext` etc are Jersey specific. The question is how to provide something similar under RestEasy.

One attempt was this

```
public class MyServlet extends ServletModule {
    @Provides @RequestScoped
    public UriInfo getUriInfo(@Context UriInfo info) {
        return info;
    }
}
```

but this leads to a stack overflow in Guice's injection code.

I know the @Context attribute should let me inject UriInfo under RestEasy but I can't figure out to use that within a Guice provider.

The app will be deployed on Wildfly 15.

Any help much appreciated as this is making my head spin.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a one line solution

```
public class MyServlets extends ServletModule {

  @Provides @RequestScoped
  public UriInfo getUriInfo() {
    return ResteasyProviderFactory.getContextData(UriInfo.class);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resteasy comes with the [RequestScopeModule](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/resteasy-guice/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/guice/ext/RequestScopeModule.java) that provides the UriInfo, HttpServletRequest, and others.

More info http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.6.3.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#Guice1

Comment: That's clearly the best way to do it, but something puzzles me. From the docs you linked  'Note that RequestScopeModule will already be added if any of your modules extends com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule.' One of my modules does extend ServletModule but I was not getting a binding for UriInfo. Any ideas?